# Python 3: Feather cannot serialize numpy arrays

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, feather

I'm trying to save my pandas dataframe to feather, but I'm having some problems with `values` column (It's a numpy array)...
This is my df:

```
  name   values
1 so     [1, 3, 5, 6] 
2 ed     [54968, 9, 02]
3 jon    [5, 34349, 02, ..., 345546]
```

When I try to save it:

```
with NamedTemporaryFile("w") as output_file: 
    df.to_feather(output_file.name)
*** ValueError: cannot serialize column 1 named values with dtype mixed
```

I also tried to save `values` with pickle, without success...

```
import pickle
df['values'] = pickle.dumps(out_df['values'], protocol=0)
df.to_feather(output_file.name)
*** ValueError: cannot serialize column 1 named values with dtype bytes
```

I don't want to use `csv`. What can I do?

**Edit1**

`sample` column cells are representing samples of measurements. This means that the length of samples can go from hundreds to thousands of values. Thus the length of the numpy arrays is very variable.

`df.dtypes 
values       object
name         object`

Comment: Only two columns?

Comment: Yes.. only two columns.

Comment: what's `df.dtypes`

Comment: Consider expanding your columns and then saving them. Using columns of lists kills all vectorisation benefits pandas provides.

Comment: I updated the description.

Comment: @enriquetaso how did you get around this? I'm having the same issue...

Comment: When I had a column of ragged float arrays, I was not able to use `pd.DataFrame.to_feather`, just `pd.DataFrame.to_pickle`. Can you cast your arrays to a different dtype? Maybe something like `df.values = df.values.apply(lambda _:  _.astype(np.int64))`. (swifter can help apply faster)